# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduled purging memory leak

Tags: java, image, memory-leaks, executorservice

I am trying to write a enclosed class to download images from the web that will refresh every 30 seconds.  I might want to download 1 image or I might want to download N images.  And I might want to stop downloading a certain image at any time.  I wrote the following class that works great except when I stop downloading an image memory is not being released for that task. Or if I stop all images from being downloaded memory is not released (This won't happen in production).  I have tried several different ways to achieve this.  My last attempt was to purge the tasks from the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor every 30 seconds using the same executor or with the code below a separate executor. I am also providing code to test releasing memory, although my example stops all images from being downloaded when in a real life usage I should be able only stop one image and the memory be released from that one task.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;


public class ImageLoadTask implements Runnable {

    private static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor taskExecutorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(500);
    private static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor purgeExecutorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(500);
    private static Runnable purgeRunnable = () -> purge();
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;
    private URL pictureURL;
    private Consumer<BufferedImage> successMethod;
    private Consumer<String> failMethod;
    private ImageURLStreamHandler streamHandler = new ImageURLStreamHandler();

    private boolean displaySuccess = false;
    private boolean displayError = false;
    private boolean isCancelled = false;

    static {
        taskExecutorService.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
        taskExecutorService.setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
        taskExecutorService.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);

        purgeExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(purgeRunnable, 30L, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public ImageLoadTask(String url) {
        try {
            this.pictureURL = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            if(failMethod != null) {
                failMethod.accept(e.getMessage()); ;
            }
            if(displayError) {
                System.out.println("(ImageLoadTask) URL is malformed: " + url+"\n"+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public ImageLoadTask(String url, Consumer<BufferedImage> successMethod) {
        this(url);
        this.successMethod = successMethod;
    }

    public ImageLoadTask(String url, Consumer<BufferedImage> successMethod, Consumer<String> failMethod) {
        this(url, successMethod);
        this.failMethod = failMethod;
    }

    public void start() {
        scheduledFuture = taskExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0L, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if(isCancelled)
            return;

        isCancelled = true;
        scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
        scheduledFuture = null;
        pictureURL = null;
        successMethod = null;
        failMethod = null;
        streamHandler = null;

        taskExecutorService.remove(this);
        taskExecutorService.purge();
    }

    public static void purge() {
        System.out.println("Purging");
        taskExecutorService.purge();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!isCancelled) {
            try {
                BufferedImage image = loadImage(pictureURL);
                if(displaySuccess) {
                    System.out.println("Image received for url " + pictureURL);
                }
                if(successMethod != null && !isCancelled) {
                    successMethod.accept(image); ;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(failMethod != null && !isCancelled) {
                    failMethod.accept(e.getMessage());
                }
                if(displayError) {
                    System.out.println("Error occured retrieving image for url: " + pictureURL +"\n"+ e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayError(boolean displayError) {
        this.displayError = displayError;
    }

    public void displaySuccess(boolean displaySuccess) {
        this.displaySuccess = displaySuccess;
    }

    private BufferedImage loadImage(URL input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input == null!");
        }

        InputStream istream = null;
        try {
            istream = streamHandler.openConnection(input).getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IIOException("Can't get input stream from URL!", e);
        }
        ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(istream);
        BufferedImage bi;
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(stream);
            if (bi == null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        } finally {
            istream.close();
        }
        return bi;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        System.out.println("finalize");
    }

    class ImageURLStreamHandler extends URLStreamHandler {

        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            URL target = new URL(url.toString());
            URLConnection connection = target.openConnection();
            // Connection settings
            connection.setConnectTimeout(60000); // 1 min
            connection.setReadTimeout(60000); // 1 min
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

Test App:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageLoadTaskTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Gui gui = new Gui();
            }
        });
    }

    static class Gui extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private List<ImageLoadTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        private boolean running = false;

        private JButton startStopButton = new JButton("Start");
        private JButton purgeButton = new JButton("Purge");

        private ActionListener startStopListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(running) {
                    stopTasks();
                } else {
                    startTasks();
                }
            }
        };


        private ActionListener purgeListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ImageLoadTask.purge();
            }
        };

        public Gui() {
            setTitle("Image Load Task Test");
            setBounds(250, 250, 300, 150); // Size
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
            setContentPane(contentPanel);

            startStopButton.addActionListener(startStopListener);
            contentPanel.add(startStopButton);


            purgeButton.addActionListener(purgeListener);
            contentPanel.add(purgeButton);

            setVisible(true);
        }

        private void startTasks() {
            running = true;
            System.out.println("Starting tasks");
            for(int i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
                ImageLoadTask task = new ImageLoadTask("http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image" + i, this::success, this::fail);
                task.start();
                tasks.add(task);
            }
            startStopButton.setText("Stop");
        }

        private void stopTasks() {
            running = false;
            System.out.println("Stopping " + tasks.size() + " tasks");
            for(ImageLoadTask task : tasks) {
                task.stop();
            }
            tasks.clear();
            startStopButton.setText("Start");
            System.out.println("Stopped tasks ");
            //ImageLoadTask.purge();
        }

        private void success(BufferedImage image) {
            //System.out.println("Success!");
        }

        private void fail(String message) {
            //System.out.println("Fail! "+ message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't close your 'stream' when you interrupt `ImageIO.read(stream)`.

Comment: Do you have a solution?  I have tried several things and it's still not working properly.

Comment: As the first step place 'stream.close()' to the 'finally' block.

Comment: Also make 'isCancelled' AtomicBoolean as your code is not thread safe.

Comment: When I add stream.close to the finally block I get 
java.io.IOException: closed
 at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.checkClosed(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:110)
 at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.close(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:857)
 at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.close(FileCacheImageInputStream.java:250)

Comment: Seems like closing 'stream' also closes 'istream', so try to close 'stream' first. And you cal always wrap the 'close' call in try..catch or use apache IOUtil.closeQuietly().

Comment: Thanks Alex!  I got it working.  I thought the memory usage would drop after stopping but apparently the threads are kept alive.  But at least memory doesn't keep going up after stop and starting!.

Comment: You create 2 ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor instances with core pool size of 500 each, meaning you will always have 1000 threads even if there is no single work. If you don't want it, create them with say core pool size of 2. Second, I'd suggest making the executors non-static - static context and garbage collectors don't really match.